# AutoMapper throws AutoMapperConfigurationException for one mapping but not for another

Tags: automapper

I have a test which calls `Mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`

I am getting a `AutoMapperConfigurationException` when I try to map an `IReadOnlyCollection` to a `List`, but only the second time I try to do this.

I am on AutoMapper version 6.0.2. edit: I ran this on the latest version 6.1.1 and still got this error.

I have 4 classes.

- `FooRow`
- `Foo`
- `BarRow`
- `Bar`

I have the following mappings.

1. `CreateMap<FooRow, Foo>`
2. `CreateMap<IReadOnlyCollection<FooRow>, List<Foo>>`
3. `CreateMap<BarRow, Bar>`
4. `CreateMap<IReadOnlyCollection<BarRow>, List<Bar>>`

Only #4 fails. I am given the error `Unmapped properties: Capacity`. Now, obviously for #4 I can add `.ForMember(d => d.Capacity, o => o.Ignore)` however I am more interested in I must do this for the second mapping of `Bar` but not `Foo`.

Comment: As a note I know that just having #1 and #3 is enough for the mapping to work, perhaps what I am doing above is just wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth trying to remove the collection mappings, given that AutoMapper has built-in support for arrays and lists:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

Comment: The above link will point back [Automapper's Github Main Page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).  Try to use this link http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html